# Docusign error "consent required" when trying to authenticate with jwt

Tags: docusignapi

I know it's recommended to use Authorization Coe Grant, but I'm running into authentication issues when I try to implement JWT auth.

```
try
            {
                _docusignAuthenticationService.AuthenticateFromJwt();
            }
            catch (ApiException apiExp)
            {
                // Consent for impersonation must be obtained to use JWT Grant
                if (apiExp.Message.Contains("consent_required"))
                {
                    return Redirect(BuildConsentURL());
                }
            }

private string BuildConsentURL()
        {
            return "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth" + "?response_type=code" +
                "&scope=signature%20impersonation" +
                "&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" +
                "&redirect_uri=" + "http://localhost:63849";
        }
```

Am I missing a step in configuring my account to use JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT requires each user consent once for a given app (based on the IK).
This can be done per user, or using admin consent - for the entire org.
[Larry blog post talks all about it.](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent)
Your code looks correct. Did you hit the exception? did the browser open and ask your for consent? and if so - did you then try again? using the same account?

**Update:** the issue has to do with having different scopes for consent vs. when making the JWT token request. The set of scopes must be the same and must always include "impersonation."

Comment: Yes, I hit the exception every time. The browser never makes it to the consent screen after I log in with my client ID.

Comment: If the browser never shows you the consent screen, it sounds like you're not actually accessing the consent URL. If you are immediately taken to your redirect URL, you might try adding `&prompt=login` to your url and confirm you're granting consent as the user you are attempting to impersonate.

Comment: "login with my client ID" seems odd. You mean user/password for the account you use to create the clientID?

Comment: Also, this may be obvious, but I assume client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
is replaced with your actual clientID when you make the call, right?

Comment: @InbarGazit 1) Yes the client_id param is he actual client ID for making the call. 2) "login with client id" - sorry if that was unclear, I meant being prompted to log in to be able to authorize the grant

Comment: According to Larry's blog, I'm trying to grant individual consent, but after logging in with my credentials, it just redirects back to my specified redirect url instead of taking me to the consent screen

Comment: that suggests you already have consent. There's a way to confirm this. by going to https://account-d.docusign.com/me/#/appconsent

Comment: can you share the code of AuthenticateFromJwt() ?

Comment: OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                  "XXXXX", // Integration Key 
                   "YYYYY", // API UserName
                   "account-d.docusign.com", // Auth Server                    
DocusignHelper.ReadFileContent(DocusignHelper.PrepareFullPrivateKeyFilePath(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/private.key"))), // RSA Private Key
                   1000,
                   new List<string> { "click.manage", "signature" });
```
This is where the error is thrown to "consent_required" - I also checked the link you provided as well

Comment: Can you re-open that link to consent (the one that doesn't prompt you ) and open it in a new incognito brwoser?

Comment: Is it possible for me to reach out to you via email for a screenshare?

Comment: sure - inbar.gazit@docusign.com